# Conditional Where Clause Help Needed - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Good morning all, hoping you can help me out with something I'm dealing with.  I'm not positive that this would be a conditional where clause but it feels like it.

I have a table that holds default values for a screen.  The row may be state specific or may apply to all states.  The stte_name column is loaded with a default value of 'XX' when the row is not state specific.

When querying this table I will be providing the following as criteria:

- @screen_name
- @ctl_name
- @stte_name

I would like to retrieve rows where all three critera are met and rows where the @screen_name and @ctl_name criteria are met and the stte_name equals the column default of 'XX' when there is no match on state.

My results should look like this if I set @stte_name = 'NY':

```
screen_name ctl_name    stte_name   dflt_value
Screen 1    control 1   NY          Hello
Screen 1    control 2   XX          World
Screen 1    control 3   XX          !
```

My results should look like this if I set @stte_name = 'FL':

```
screen_name ctl_name    stte_name   dflt_value
Screen 1    control 1   NY          Bonjour
Screen 1    control 2   XX          World
Screen 1    control 3   XX          !
```

I've been working at this for a little while and haven't been able to manipulate the state criteria to produce the desired results.  I've tried sub-queries, full outer joins and a multitude of other angles.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.defaults_t
(
    screen_name VARCHAR(10),
    ctl_name    VARCHAR(10),
    stte_name   CHAR(2),
    dflt_value  VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT PK_defaults_t PRIMARY Key CLUSTERED
    (
        screen_name ASC,
        ctl_name    ASC,
        stte_name   ASC
    )
);

INSERT INTO defaults_t (screen_name, ctl_name, stte_name, dflt_value)
VALUES  ('Screen 1', 'control 1', 'NY', 'Hello'),
        ('Screen 1', 'control 1', 'XX', 'Bonjour'),
        ('Screen 1', 'control 2', 'XX', 'World'),
        ('Screen 1', 'control 3', 'XX', '!');


DECLARE @screen_name    VARCHAR(10),
        @ctl_name       VARCHAR(10),
        @stte_name      CHAR(2)

SELECT  @screen_name = 'Screen 1',
        @ctl_name    = 'control 1',
        @stte_name   = 'NY';
        
SELECT
    screen_name,
    ctl_name,
    stte_name,
    dflt_value
FROM
    dbo.defaults_t
WHERE
        screen_name = @screen_name
    AND ctl_name    = @ctl_name
    AND stte_name   ?????;
```

Comment: What's wrong basic boolean logic `AND (stte_name = @stte_name OR stte_name = 'XX')`?

Comment: That would return both 'Hello' and 'Bonjour'.  I need to return the state specific row if there is one and the 'XX' row if there isn't one.

Comment: That isn't what you state in your question; you state you want both: *"I would like to retrieve rows where all three critera are met **and** rows where the `@screen_name` and `@ctl_name` criteria are met and the stte_name equals the column default of 'XX'."*

Comment: I can see how that might be misleading, I've edited that statement.

Comment: WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM defaults_t WHERE stte_name = ?problem_value?) AND stte_name = ?problem_value?) OR (NOT EXISTS ... AND ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an OUTER JOIN for this, but it really suggests that the defaults should probably be in a seperate table.  Anyway, something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.screen_name,
    t.ctl_name,
    coalesce(t2.stte_name,t.stte_name) stte_name,
    coalesce(t2.dflt_value,t.dflt_value) dflt_value
FROM
    dbo.defaults_t t
LEFT JOIN DBO.defaults_t   t2
   on t.ctl_name = t2.ctl_name
   and t.screen_name = t2.screen_name
   and t2.stte_name = @stte_name 
WHERE t.stte_name   = 'XX';
```